# Auto Update Cart Quantity without Reloading Activity in Android

Tags: android, cart

I have added the update function into the add and sub onclick, however it is reloading the activity once quantity added or subtracted. Below is my code:

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            //Auto Update Cart Pasted from onClickUpdateCartBtn()
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(Cart.this, getResources().getString(R.string.please_wait),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.processing_request_response), true);
            progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            updateCartArr = new JSONArray();
            itemIDSArray = new JSONArray();
            itemQTYsArray = new JSONArray();
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutMain);
        try {
            String val = ((TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.qty)).getText().toString();
            ((TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.qty)).setText("" + (Integer.parseInt(val) + 1));
            
            //Auto Update Cart Pasted from onClickUpdateCartBtn()
            JSONObject qtyObj = new JSONObject();
            for (int i = 0; i < mainObject.getJSONObject("cart").getJSONArray("products").length(); i++) {
                View child = ll.findViewWithTag(i);
                qtyObj.put(mainObject.getJSONObject("cart").getJSONArray("products").getJSONObject(i).getString("key"), (((TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.qty)).getText().toString()));
            }
            jo.put("quantity", qtyObj);
            new MobikulMakeConnection(Cart.this).execute("updateCart", jo.toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        //Auto Update Cart Pasted from onClickUpdateCartBtn()
        } /*catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        //Auto Update Cart Pasted from onClickUpdateCartBtn()
        }*/ catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        //Original
        }
    }
});

child.findViewById(R.id.sub_qty).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
                //Auto Update Cart Pasted from onClickUpdateCartBtn()
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(Cart.this, getResources().getString(R.string.please_wait),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.processing_request_response), true);
            progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            updateCartArr = new JSONArray();
            itemIDSArray = new JSONArray();
            itemQTYsArray = new JSONArray();
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutMain);

            try {
            String val = ((TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.qty)).getText().toString();
            if ((Integer.parseInt(val) - 1) >= 1)
            ((TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.qty)).setText("" + (Integer.parseInt(val) - 1));
            
            //Auto Update Cart Pasted from onClickUpdateCartBtn()
            JSONObject qtyObj = new JSONObject();
            for (int i = 0; i < mainObject.getJSONObject("cart").getJSONArray("products").length(); i++) {
                View child = ll.findViewWithTag(i);
                qtyObj.put(mainObject.getJSONObject("cart").getJSONArray("products").getJSONObject(i).getString("key"), (((TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.qty)).getText().toString()));
            }
            jo.put("quantity", qtyObj);
            new MobikulMakeConnection(Cart.this).execute("updateCart", jo.toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        //Auto Update Cart Pasted from onClickUpdateCartBtn()
        } /*catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        //Auto Update Cart Pasted from onClickUpdateCartBtn()
        }*/ catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        //Original
        }                       
    }
});
```

I was able to manage that by commenting `restartActivity()` in the updateCartResponse.

```
public void updateCartResponse(String backresult) {
    progress.dismiss();
    Log.d("updatecart", "preparing intent");
    //restartActivity();
    restartActivity();
}
```

However now this issue is the subtotal and total not updating automatically I have to go back to homepage then open the cart page again to see the updates. I'm stuck not knowing how to resolve the issue and let total and subtotal be automatically updated by quantity addition or subtraction.

The total and subtotal code:

```
                TextView subTotal = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.subTotal);
                if(!(cartObject.getString("total").equalsIgnoreCase("false"))) {
                    String subTotalPrice = "<b>" + getResources().getString(R.string.subtotal_label) + "</b> " + cartObject.getString("total");
                    subTotal.setText(Html.fromHtml(subTotalPrice));
                }else {
                    subTotal.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                linearLayoutMain.addView(child);
            }
            /******************         linearLaoyutCartTotals        ****************/
            LinearLayout linearLaoyutCartTotals = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLaoyutCartTotals);
            for (int i = 0; i < mainObject.getJSONObject("cart").getJSONArray("totals").length(); i++) {

                View child1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_cart_total, null); //child.xml

                JSONObject totalObject = mainObject.getJSONObject("cart").getJSONArray("totals").getJSONObject(i);
                Log.d("product", "hai" + mainObject.getJSONObject("cart").getJSONArray("totals").getJSONObject(i));
                TextView tv1 = (TextView) child1.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
                tv1.setText(totalObject.getString("title"));

                TextView tv2 = (TextView) child1.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
                tv2.setText(totalObject.getString("text"));
                linearLaoyutCartTotals.addView(child1);
            }
            TextView totalAmountOnTop = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalAmountOnTop);
            if(mainObject.getJSONObject("cart").getJSONArray("totals").length() == 0)
                totalAmountOnTop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            else
                totalAmountOnTop.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.total_amount) + mainObject.getJSONObject("cart").getJSONArray("totals").getJSONObject(mainObject.getJSONObject("cart").getJSONArray("totals").length() - 1).getString("text"));
        }
    } else {
        errorTv.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.no_item_in_cart));
        emptyCart.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.empty_cart));
        errorTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.proceedToCheckout2).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.linearLaoyutBtns).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("customerData", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("cartItems", "0");
        editor.apply();

        LinearLayout linearLaoyutDiscount = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLaoyutDiscountTop);
        linearLaoyutDiscount.removeAllViews();
        linearLaoyutDiscount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    findViewById(R.id.main_progress_bar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (!mainObject.getJSONObject("cart").has("products")) {
        findViewById(R.id.svHeader).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.scroll_view).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.d("if", "if");
    } else {
        findViewById(R.id.svHeader).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.scroll_view).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.d("else", "else");
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: don't see anything related to restarting the activity. Can you add your code for `onPostExecute()` method? You might be doing something wacky there

Comment: @Abhijit thanks for the comment I was able to manage the reload of activity by commenting `restartActivity()` in the updateCartResponse. I've updated my question and mention the first solution., The issue now the subtotal and total aren't automatically updating without activity reload so I have to reload the activity in an way to get the updated results. Kindly check total and subtotal code if I'm missing anything, thanks in advanced.

Comment: hard to say from the code you have but looks like you are not updating the text in total/subtotal views with the new json data. make sure you are parsing out the response and setting it to the corresponding views

Comment: Can you advise how possible to achieve that as we tested different options with no luck

Comment: I'm get sendUserActionEvent() mView == null from logcat

Comment: sorry, I missed your comments. Are you still having trouble with this issue? let me know

Comment: It's ok thanks I was able to change the command and update the activity without reloading. Thank you again